# Add an arrow under the active menu item in HTML+CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to generate a menu like the following:

[image]

There are several items in the menu and the active one has an arrow after it.
The menu items are  tags like the following code:

```
<div class="menuCenter">
     <div class="linksWrapper">
      <a href="#">Home</a>
      <a class="menuCenterLinkLeft" href="#">Plans & Pricing</a>
      <a class="menuCenterLinkLeft" href="#">Sign In</a>
      <a class="menuCenterLinkLeft active" href="#">Sign Up</a>
      <a class="menuCenterLinkLeft" href="#">Contact</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

I tryied two options: 
1- Absolutely positioning the arrow image with javascript. I have problems when resizing the page.
2- Using the :after pseudo element, like this:

```
.linksWrapper a.active:after
{
    content: url("images/arrowImg.png");
    position: relative;
    left: -40px;
    top: 30px; 
}
```

The problem with this approach was the horizontal alignment of the arrow. It should be below the center of the link and I could not achive that.
I can use HTML5 or CSS 3.

Any help?

Comment: Are your navigation list items fixed or fluid widths?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
.linksWrapper a.active:after {
    content: url("images/arrowImg.png");
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    top: 30px;
    margin-left: - <width-of-your-image> / 2; /* negative number!*/
}
```

sidenote: I avoid putting `{` on a newline, since it may have nasty effects in javascript.

The trick is `left:50%;` combined with correcting the position by setting it back half width via `margin-left`.

See **[example](http://jsfiddle.net/u85as/1/)**.

Comment: Don't you need to add content: ""; to your pseudo-elements if not it won't show the image.

Comment: @Vennsoh I know, I'm one year late, but as you can see, it has the content attribute set with the image url.

Answer (score 2):

The absolute positioning approach should work, you need to put the arrow inside of another div that has `position:relative` defined, so that the absolute coordinates are relative to this parent div, instead of being relative to the body element.

However, I would go with this approach instead:

Make the arrow a part of the background image of the actual a.active items - this way it will center with `background-position` and you don't need any scripting!

Answer (score -1):

I put this together really quick..

http://jsfiddle.net/8Sqwq/1/

Because I wasn't too sure how flexible your code could be, this is the best I could come up with.

Which ever href has the classname of .active will inherit the arrow

// I updated the fiddle to show it in action.

Comment: I like this answer too. I wish I could mark 2 answers as correct.

Comment: You link in the fiddle broke.