# CSS Arrow image centered under active menu item doesn't show

Tags: html, css, image, menu, css-shapes

I would like to put an arrow image (png) centered under my active item menu instead of having my actual blue border-line. I tried to modified my css with no luck, the image doesn't appear. do you know what I doing wrong ?

**My CSS** :

```
    #cssmenu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 12pt;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #94adc1; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #f2f1f2;
    zoom: 1;
    text-align:center; 
}

#cssmenu ul:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
}

#cssmenu ul:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

#cssmenu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 4px;
    list-style: none;

}

#cssmenu li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    color: #123b59; 
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 20px 7px 20px;
    border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
}

#cssmenu li a:hover {
    content: url("images/arrowmenunav.png");
    /*color: #6c8cb5;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00b8fd;*/
}

#cssmenu li.active a {
    /*display: inline;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #00b8fd;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;*/
    content: url("images/arrowmenunav.png");

}

#cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height:94px; 
}
```

**My menu in HTML** :

```
<div id="cssmenu">
    <ul id="list">
        <li><a href="#home" >home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#home2">home2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#newsletter">newsletter</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Is your image url correct? That path would imply that inside the folder where your css is there is a folder called images

Comment: Hi Smegger, yes, the path of image is correct. That's why I don't unerstand why it doesn't show.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10391343/1045672 might help.

Comment: Hi Teffi, thanks for the help and the link. I have already shown this link. I tried to do the same on my code but with no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing I can see is this line

```
#cssmenu li.active a {
    content: url("images/arrowmenunav.png");
}
```

Should be this:

```
#cssmenu li.active a:after {
    content: url("images/arrowmenunav.png");
}
```

**I've setup this jsfiddle to show it in a bit more detail** http://jsfiddle.net/e3WEs/2/

In this I've used a 20px by 20px placeholder image. The negative margin should be half of your image width (10px in this case) to centre align it to the parent element.

**Here is a version that will work in older browsers too (IE7 and below)**
http://jsfiddle.net/e3WEs/3/

Comment: Your fiddle appears to be broken to me.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the link in my answer. I'd not pressed update on jsfiddle

Comment: Hi Smegger, thx for your reply. I fixed the issue. My only problem is that the arrow image is correctly positioned. content:url("images/arrowmenunav.png") bottom center no-repeat; I don't manage to launch your fiddle.

Comment: Smegger, I took a look at your fiddle. For the hover : #cssmenu li a:hover, should I add the same like in #cssmenu li.active a:after ?

Comment: Take a look at this fiddle with a hover effect on it. http://jsfiddle.net/e3WEs/5/

Answer (score 0):

Another option if you don't want to use :after. :after is pretty much not supported by old browsers if that concerns you.

http://jsfiddle.net/f3SQx/

Mark-up

```
<li><a href="#home">home</a>
<div class="active"></div>
</li>
```

CSS

```
.active {
 position:absolute;
 width:30px;
 height:30px;
 top:100%;
 margin-left:32%;
 content: url("images/arrowmenunav.png");
}
```

Comment: True, browser support for generated content for psuedo elements is IE8 onwards http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Aafter
If browser support is an issue he should use a background-image rather than content in your example.

Answer (score 0):

> Please add **z-index** values  to **`#cssmenu li a`**
>
> hope this helped you